# Unzip a password protected zip file with Powershell code by using 7-zip in JAMS scheduling tool

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, 7zip

I am trying to Unzip a password protected zip file with Powershell code by using 7-zip in JAMS scheduling tool. I am trying with below code, it works for unzip the normal files. Please suggest the correct way to pass the password, so that i can make it work for unzip the password protected zip files.

```
cd C:\Program Files\7-zip
7z e -tzip "C:\Users\Work\" -o "C:\Users\Work\"
```

My code works for unzip the normal files. Please suggest the correct way to pass the password to this code, so that i can make it work for unzip the password protected zip files.

Comment: Run `7z e -?` to see the relevant options :)

Comment: `-p` is the parameter for specifying a password; alternatively provide the password via the pipeline. `cd C:\Program Files\7-zip` won't work in PowerShell unless you quote `C:\Program Files\7-zip`. You're seemingly passing a _folder_ instead of an _archive file_ to `7z e`